# Is counting Latin squares #P-complete?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, enumerative-combinatorics, latin-square

I feel like I should know the answer to this.  I did some Googling and didn't easily find the answer...

**Question**: Is counting Latin squares [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete)?

Obviously the corresponding decision problem "Is this a Latin square?" belongs to P ⊆ NP, so the Latin-square enumeration problem is in [#P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP).

We have:

- [Valiant's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-completeness_of_01-permanent) shows that computing the permanent of (0,1)-matrices is #P-complete, and the number of extensions of a Latin rectangle can be rephrased in terms of a (0,1)-matrix permanent.
- [Colbourn's (1984)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(84)90075-1) result that completing partial Latin squares is NP-complete (see also [Easton and Parker (2001)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-218X(00)00282-1)).
- [Gessel (1987)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-16/issue-1/Counting-Latin-rectangles/bams/1183553671.full) showed that the number of Latin rectangles with a fixed number of rows is P-recursive.

I'm not sure what's known beyond this.

Comment: I think the question is a bit misguided - computing counting functions $f(n)$ is best framed not as a #P type question, but using other notions.  I recommend reading my survey on this:  https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/ICM-paper9.pdf

Comment: Actually that reminds me of Gessel's P-recursive result for Latin rectangles; perhaps it's better to think about it this way.

Comment: To emphasize Igor’s objection: the issue is that the input is just a single number.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose you could input an empty nxn matrix and ask how many completions it has to a Latin square.  Although perhaps this is an instance of the more general problem "how many completions does this partial Latin square have"?  Indeed, #P-complete problems studied seem to have a large number of inputs of the same size (like a (0,1)-matrix).

Comment: *#P-complete problems studied seem to have a large number of inputs of the same size* – And, there’s a reason for that. Since your problem only depends on the size of the input, it is in FP/poly. Thus it cannot be #P-complete unless PP, and consequently all of the couting hierarchy CH, is included in P/poly, and collapses to CH=MA=coMA.